# SQL Query not displaying all data? Displays some data

Tags: mysql, join

```
Select `student_id`, first_name, last_name, label, student_scores 
FROM `score` 
INNER JOIN student AS STAB on STAB.id = `student_id` 
INNER JOIN course AS ctab on ctab.cid = `course_id`
```

[image: Studenscores not showing]

This is my sql query im using in xammp for my java project on netbeans. The problem is firstname, last name and label display the data but student scores does not. However if I put the code like this:

```
Select `student_id`, first_name, last_name, student_scores, label
FROM `score` 
INNER JOIN student AS STAB on STAB.id = `student_id` 
INNER JOIN course AS ctab on ctab.cid = `course_id`
```

Studentscores displays but label does not.

[image: Label not showing]

How do i fix this so both my label and student course appear in my sql query?

Comment: Try select columns in different order (name last), if it is consistently only showing 4 columns try expand the view or something. Also I would check that Options link just above the Grid.

Comment: The query looks fine.  This looks more to me to be an issue in the tool you're using to run the query, in options or something.

Comment: Tried moving student id to the end of query, no luck.
Tried moving last name and first name both to the end and only still displays  up to 4 columns